# Is there a way to tell how many more times I can use an item?

Tags: mario-kart-8

There are a few new items in Mario Kart 8 that have a variable amount of uses to them such as the boomerang flower and fireball.  Is there a way to tell how many more times you can use these items or should I just mash them as fast as I can whenever I start using them like the golden mushroom from the previous games?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All variable-usage items have a white bar wrapping around the inside of the container showing how much power's left in it. For some items, using them takes a small chunk off the timer, while for others using them continuously takes just as long as using them rarely.

[image: Potted Piranha item as demonstration.]